# Responsive Design: max-device-width, max-width and min-device-pixel-ratio

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I am currently on an website which needs to be fully responsive in screen width and pixel density. My major problem is how do i get the responsiveness for HiDPI devices such as the galaxy s4.

I have read about the min-device-pixel-ratio but I do not fully get it and my attempts do not work. All my less/css is using rems as units, so basically I should be able to just manipulate the font-size ond the html tag, to get what I want, right? But maybe this is bullshit?

However, I wanted to ask for best practises and tips and tricks.
Whats important to me is, that I don't have multiple versions or subdomains for desktop and mobile devices. I want to do it all with media queries.

Thank you very much in advance. I really appreciate your help!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidpi only means that 1 css pixel is rendered with 3x3 actual pixels (this varies for devices, iPhone pixel density is 2- so on iPhone 1 css pixel is made from 4 actual LCD pixels.). Websites on galaxy s4 are still rendered as 360x640px with pixel density 3, so you don't need any additional css for HiDPI devices.

you only need to add this meta tag in year head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

and apply css as for regular non HiDPI device.

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you very much... however, on some mobile devices are some text contents pretty big. but not on every device and not all texts. any idea on that?

Comment: hard to tell without additional details. I know that old android browsers (below 4.1) don't support rems

Answer (score 0):

To addition what pankijs wrote, notice, that different browsers (chrome, android native browser, firefox etc.) handle media queries in different way. For example if you use:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px)
```

it would work on Desktop Chrome browser and on android smartphone browser, but not on Safari on iPhone. To make it work on Safari you have to use:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px)
```

The conclusion is that you need test your media queries on physical devices :) For more information, check this page: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/